# Implement Android Service for Sensors?

Tags: android, service, background, sensors

I am currently making an app that will control and make use of the light sensor. As such I need data for when the ambient lighting changes (via the light sensor in lux). How would I make it so that when the user exits my application that it stays running in the background with the ability to collect data and make changes to the system?

Comment: The whole point of a Service is to be long running even after an Activity has closed. Just don't stop the Service when the Activity exits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not un-register your sensors from your sensor manager on OnPause() your sensor event listener events should still be getting being fired at regular intervals. You should then be-able to do what ever functionality you need from there. However if the user stops the program and the system sees that its been inactive for a while and its system memory is running low there is a possibility that the android OS will kill the task thinking its not needed. I am sure there are some flags or something to be called to stop this from occurring but I cant tell you off the top of my head.

You could also look into writing a background service if you want it to run all once the user boots-up.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-practices

Answer (score 0):

[Best Practices for Accessing and Using Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-practices)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.